# MongoDB sort by two possible properties

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregate-functions

I have a collection that contains properties, and each property can have an "override" value.
Where overrides is a subcollection that stores subdocuments of override values.

I.e.

```
{
     "color":"red",
     "overrides": [
          {
                property:"color",
                value:"blue"
          }
      ]
```

}

There can only be 1 override subdocument per actualy property

I'd like to be able to sort by `color` - but....if a `color` override exists (then that will take precedence over the actual `color` property.

So in the example above, the value of blue would override the actual `color` property of "red" and would get sorted first.

So the algorithm I'm looking for is something like, `"sort by color...but if a color override exists..then use that value instead"`.

I take it I'd have to "unroll" all values and then sort (using an aggregate)

Any ideas on how to do this and what will the performance impact be for ~2k documents (searching by just color is rather fast). Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you create a top level property, for example color_override and create an index before run a sort operation. Don't be afraid of duplicate date.

Comment: Mm..top-level property would've been the best way for this schema to have been initially designed. It would be a little tedious to retroactively fix the data though. 

Is there really now way to do this with the array of sub-documents?

Comment: The way that I know is with $unwind. You could $unwind (explode) your array in order to have one object per each element of the array. So you could next create a sort using the property that you want.

Comment: @OscarLópez So I'd have to `$unwind` but then also apply some conditional logic to see if an "unwinded" override existed per a property. Know what I mean? Looks like I'm gonna have to tinker with a pipeline

Comment: I understand, In my experience is not the best option make a complicated pipeline. You will end without knowing how well perform the query. Despite of that, you can try to add this extra property modifying the results with $project or $addFields and sort by two fields.

Comment: Mm...I thought about that with `$addFields`. Got close, but still need to tinker with query to figure it out